# For webdav the choices are activex or shared web folders, right?

Tags: webdav

In our environment we have IE clients looking over a web page with a document list.  When the user clicks on a document we can start MS Word from the activex control Sharepoint Team Services Client (OWSSUPP.DLL) or expose the document list via a Shared Folder that Word can access.

Are there other choices?

Answer (score 0):

One option, which would probably be frowned upon by sys admins, is to create a vbs script file on the fly that the user can choose to download and execute. The contents would be something like

`CreateObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.2").EditDocument("http://...url here")`

Alternatively you could display the url and instruct the user to copy and paste it into the appropriate program (MS Word etc). Adding a button to automatically copy it to the clipboard using something like [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) might make it less of a chore for the user.

Otherwise unfortunately I think those are your options. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft Office now installs plugins for all 4 major browsers. So you can open for editing MS Office documents in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE.